# How to add a field to a struct dynamically?

Tags: solidity, struct

Suppose we have a proxy contract that separates Data layer from Logic layer.
We have a `struct` in Data contract, like this:

```
struct person {
    uint id;
    string name;
}
mapping(address => person) persons;
```

We have deployed this contract and the Dapp users have entered data in it.

Now suppose we want to change the logic contract and add a `birth_year` field to the struct. how can we make this change to the struct dynamically? Its final form would be as follows:

```
struct person {
    uint id;
    string name;
    uint birth_year;
}
mapping(address => person) persons;
```

Even assembly language is acceptable, but sure Solidity is better.

Answer (score 1):

Struct is not the solution you want. try this method, it will solve your problem:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >0.8.0 <0.9.0;

contract DynamicFields{
    address owner;
    constructor(){owner=msg.sender;}
    
    string[] fields=["name","address","id"]; // can add more fields
    mapping(address=>string[]) persons;
    
    function AddField(string memory newField) public {
        if(msg.sender==owner){
            fields.push(newField);
        }
    }


    // pass data like (0x12asd... , ["name of user","address of user", "id", "more fields if added"])
    function AddOrUpdatePersonDetails(address personAddress, string[] memory personDetails) public {
        if(msg.sender==owner){
            persons[personAddress]=personDetails;
        }
    }
    
    function GetPersonDetails(address add) public view returns(string[] memory){
        return persons[add];
    }
     // it will return data like : ["name of user","address of user", "id", "more fields if added"]
    
}
```

note: this method will save all data in string form, even integers will be in the string format, not in uint.

if you have any better solution, please tell, i'm also in search of a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically possible in interpreted languages like Python and Javascript.

And it is typically not possible in strongly-typed languages like C and Solidity.

Comment: So may be possible in smart contracts assembly language.

Comment: @AlirezaZojaji: No, it isn't.

Comment: Viper language is a Python-based language. All Python commands finally is interpretted to bytecode equal to Assembly language. So if it is possible in Viper, probabelt it should be possible in assembly language. Isn't it?

Comment: @AlirezaZojaji: First of all, your question is tagged `solidity`. Second, I sincerely doubt that this is allowed in Vyper. The bottom line is that interpreted-language programs are executed on an interpreter, which may allow this. The bytecode is executed on the EVM, which does not allow this.